# Why is useMemo used in the Material-UI documentation for the autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am specifically referring to [this demo](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#google-maps-place) in the autocomplete documentation.

In the google maps example there is a throttled function which is returned from a `useMemo` with an empty array as second parameter. But what is the point of the memoization here if the array is missing?

```
const fetch = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      throttle((request, callback) => {
        autocompleteService.current.getPlacePredictions(request, callback);
      }, 200),
    [],
  );
```

Wouldn't in the example make more sense to replace this flow:

> useEffect => useMemo => throttle => fetch

with just:

> useEffect => throttle => fetch

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question, but the empty array means the throttle function will only be initialised once on mount. Otherwise the throttle function would run on every render.

Comment: And the fetch variable is used in the dependencies on `useEffect` which is why it is memoized. Typically it is a good idea to `useCallback`/`useMemo` when the variable is in depdendencies of a `useEffect`.

Comment: The `useMemo` DOES have a second parameter. An empty array. If you mean why is there nothing in that array, that means it's created once when the component mounts, then never again. If they didn't put it in the memo, then every time the component renders, this throttled function would be recreated, thus defeating the point of throttling

Comment: @Jayce444 yes that's what I meant thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`throttle` is a function creator:

- What it does: create another function whose job is to prevent the original function from being invoked repeatedly. (definition is oversimplified for the sake of this answer).
- What it does not: execute the original function in any way.

```js
function throttle(fn, threshhold, scope) {
  return function () {
    let isInvokedRepeatedly = // some programming magic

    if (!isInvokedRepeatedly) {
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }
  };
}
```

So if you call `throttle()` directly in the render method like this.

```js
render() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');
  const fetch = throttle(() => api.request(inputValue));

  ...
}
```

This means that every time the component renders, a new instance of fetch is re-created, thus reseting any internal values of the throttle function.

That can be solved by only instantiating the function only one time at the first render using `useMemo` or `useCallback` and passing an empty array as dependencies.

```js
render() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');
  // You can also use React.useMemo()

  // memoize the callback. I personally prefer this method.
  const fetch = React.useCallback(throttle(() => api.request(inputValue)), []);

  // memoize the result which is the callback. Same as above
  const fetch1 = React.useMemo(() => {
    return throttle(() => api.request(inputValue));
  }, [] /* no dependency: callback only run once at startup */);

  ...
}
```